# Contact fields not accessible in SOQL Query on User

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, query, community-cloud

I am working with Community users and I need to query both their **User** and **Contact** details at the same time.

When I am performing a relationship query like

```
[Select Id, Email, ContactId, Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName From User where...]
```

I am getting the correct field values from User, but the fields from Contact have the value `null`.

If I query these objects separately, I am able to see the values from the Contact object's fields.
I am system admin and I have access on all fields specified in the SOQL query. 
The OWD for Contact is Controlled by Parent and for User is private.

I could do the queries separately in my code but I wonder what is the cause why the relationship query is giving such a result?

Comment: I'm having no issues using the same query and getting the contact info. Are you filtering on users that have a ContactId?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I am filtering for users which have a Community profile, therefore all of them will have ContactId. Also, I am in a test class and the only users I have there have a ContactId for sure. And besides I can see in my logs that ContactId exists but the fields on that Contact are not visible for some reason.

Comment: It might be more related to your test class if you can include any code snippets from it. You can confirm that the query works outside of the test context first to narrow it down.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves unfortunately the code is work-related so I cannot explicitly share it. I just insert a contact an a user related to it. Of course I set the first name, last and so on on the contact. I have also tried to do this kind of query in anonymous window on effective data and the same issue happens. Split queries work, but relationship query does not.

Comment: Can you just share the User creation code and the SOQL `WHERE` criteria?

Comment: @HemantJain as I said above, it is work related. I cannot explicitly share my code which contains custom fields in WHERE criteria. And honestly I do not think it is related to where condition at all because I have also tried in the anonymous to filter by the user Id. The same thing happens. User details are brought into the result, where Contact fields, whether is first name, last name, or whatever other field, apart from the contact id are not visible in the relationship query. I think this has more to do with security settings but I do not know exactly what is set up wrong.

Comment: @HemantJain on the existing users, there is the same problem. It is not related to code. I have queried with my Community User. It was Select Id, ContactId, Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName where Id='{myId}' and I cannot see Contact.FirstName and Contact.LastName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have investigated in more details and apparently, if you perform a relationship query and then display the result using `System.debug()` method, it will not display the related object's values in the log, even if those values are not *null*.

Comment: if you specify the related object in the debug log, it displays the info (ex. userRecord.Contact). It just won't display it if you only include the User object to debug (will only display user fields).